# How to create different combinations of rows from a dataset

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose i have a dataset :

```
+----+----+----+-----+----+
||col0|col2|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+-----+----+
|   t0|  10| 100|cat26|30.9|
|   t1|  20| 200|cat13|22.1|
|   t2|  30| 300|cat26|30.9|
|   t3|  40| 400|cat26|30.9|
|   t4|  50| 500|cat15|15.3|
|   t5|  60| 600|cat13|22.1|
+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

I select a sub-dataset using `where()` :

```
  Dataset<Row> subDf = dF.where("col3 = cat26 ");
```

Yielding :

```
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |col0|col2|col2|col3 |col4|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |  t0|  10| 100|cat26|30.9|
     |  t2|  30| 300|cat26|30.9|
     | t3 |  40| 400|cat26|30.9|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
```

I want to create different combinations using these three rows to form for each combination a dataset.

How to achieve just that in JAVA ?
Thank you.

UPDATE : an example of a combination is as follow :

```
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |col0|col2|col2|col3 |col4|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |  t0|  10| 100|cat26|30.9|
     |  t2|  30| 300|cat26|30.9|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
```

Another one is :

```
 +----+----+----+-----+----+
 |col0|col2|col2|col3 |col4|
 +----+----+----+-----+----+
 |  t2|  30| 300|cat26|30.9|
 |  t3|  40| 400|cat26|30.9|
 +----+----+----+-----+----+
```

Third is :

```
   +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |col0|col2|col2|col3 |col4|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |  t0|  10| 100|cat26|30.9|
     |  t3|  40| 400|cat26|30.9|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
```

And last :

```
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |col0|col2|col2|col3 |col4|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
     |  t0|  10| 100|cat26|30.9|
     |  t2|  30| 300|cat26|30.9|
     | t3 |  40| 400|cat26|30.9|
     +----+----+----+-----+----+
```

Comment: Can you add how should your combination of dataset should look like ?

Comment: See UPDATE, every  combination should look like a dataset (set of rows)

Comment: at least, every combination has two rows